# How this sum is being calculated

Tags: arithmetic-expressions, negation

I'm doing java and I'm having trouble understanding how it's calculating this sum. 5+3/2*7-8=4
How it's getting 4?

The order in which arithmetic operators are applied in
a calculation are as follows:
1. Negation, -
2. Multiplication and Division, *, /, %
3. Addition and Subtraction, +, -

Also what is negation?

Answer (score 1):

In java, when you divide two integers you receive an integer.  So in your equation, 3 / 2 = 1.  Which becomes 5 + (1 * 7) - 8 = 4

```
5 + 3 / 2 * 7 - 8 = 4
5 + 1 * 7 - 8 = 4
5 + 7 - 8 = 4
5 + -1 = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the way I understand it:
- since division and multiplication are the highest priority they will be processed first, from left to right; so 3/2 gives 1, as @Brian Cain noted; then we multiply that 1 by 7 -> that gives 7
- so far we have 5 + 7 - 8, which again processed from left to right gives 4

I'm not very much into Java, but negation seems to me like an operation related to boolean type: that's a type which takes either true or false, and by using negation (!) you flip the value between these two, but please double-check it